# Run Office 365 Graph API Queries in Blazor Server App using SDK

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a Blazor Server application on .NET 6.0. It has been registered in Azure AD and I have needed secret Ids and all from Azure after registration. I got below code from graph explorer for a "people" query as [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('jmathews4@dxc.com')/people/?$top=200](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users(%27jmathews4@dxc.com%27)/people/?$top=200)

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var people = await graphClient.Users["jmathews4@dxc.com"].People
    .Request()
    .Top(200)
    .GetAsync();
```

> I am wondering how can I get an "authProvider" instance mentioned in
> above code? Nothing has mentioned about it.

I don't want to authenticate to Office 365 from my Blazor app, but I am wishing to use my below Ids I recieved during app registration in Azure to create an instance of "authProvider".

Application (client) ID
Directory (tenant) ID
Client Secret Value
Client Secret Id

I have below API permissions.

[image]

Any lead here?

Comment: In your scenario (assuming you have your app pre-authenticated by admin, so users don't authenticate), you should go with app-only credentials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider Does it help or you are asking something else?

Comment: Thanks. Below also Ref. to the same solution and I mentioned there an error I am getting now related to invalid user

Answer (score 1):

You can create **GraphServiceClient** like this, [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider)

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "common";

// Values from app registration
var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
var clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var people = await graphClient.Users["jmathews4@dxc.com"].People
    .Request()
    .Top(200)
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got an unexpected error once tried this as "Code: ErrorInvalidUser
Message: The requested user 'jmathews4@dxc.com' is invalid.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2023-02-13T13:43:10
 request-id: a958dd2b-1c93-41c2-bce1-0088e26a9adc
 client-request-id: a958dd2b-1c93-41c2-bce1-0088e26a9adc
ClientRequestId: a958dd2b-1c93-41c2-bce1-0088e26a9adc". The same user giving result in graph explorer

Comment: I updated the question with screenshot of my API access in Azure. Based on that I tried to read Calendar as well    var calendarList = await graphClient.Users["jmathews4@dxc.com"].Calendar
      .Request()
      .GetAsync();. This too generates invalid user error. Any thing else I misssed in Azure?

Comment: @JaishMathews You have not granted the consent for your organization to use the app (look at the yellow exclamation marks on your screenshot in the "status" column)

Comment: @Nikolay I noticed that for Directory and People query. For Calendar I coudn't see a need of Admin consent there. As I mentioned above, query await graphClient.Users["jmathews4@dxc.com"].Calendar .Request() .GetAsync();. also producing invalid user.

Comment: I just noticed that even though I selected "Application" type permission, it has been added as "Delegated" type. So, I may need to login 1st to try these and that also need Admin approval. My corporate Azure AD might restrict all these. Is there a way we can try all GrapAPI without such restrictions?

Comment: For some endpoints you must admin approval there is no way to skip on this